# How display zoomcontrol on FrameLayout containing Camera?

Tags: android, android-layout

I has FrameLayout contain Camera. I want show  zoomcontrol when touch on Camera.
I design xml as: But after add zoomcontrol , Camera can't display.

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >    
                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:background="#000000" >
                </FrameLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutSlider"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:visibility="visible" >

                   <ZoomControls
                    android:id="@+id/zoomControls1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
```

How display zoomcontrol on FrameLayout containing Camera?